# Symfony HttpFoundation get single file returns null?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-http-foundation

I use symfony *HttpFoundation* for upload files, the FileBag works if I call `all()`, but if I use `get('document_name')` it return `null`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


    public function saveFileAction(Request $request) {
        dump($request->files->all());
        dump($request->files->get('document'));
    }
```

For all() I get following response:

```
FileController.php on line 175:
array:1 [▼
  "form" => array:1 [▼
    "document" => UploadedFile {#14 ▶}
  ]
]
```

What I do wrong here? Does somebody know why I can't get the single file with `get()` method? I found in symfony documentation I found that `$request->files->get('document')` should work...

Comment: Are you sure your file input's `name` attribute is not `form[document]`? If that's the case you're supposed to use `get('form')['document']`.

Comment: @Taylan my file input attribute name is exactly: form[document], and with get('form')['document'] I get index not set notice

Comment: What's the output when you just use `get('form')`?

Comment: Only _token field

Comment: You need to use get on `$request->files`. Are you maybe using it on `$request->request`?

Comment: No, you can see in my example that is use `$request->files->get('document')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->files->get("document")` is correct if the POST field really is named as this. (Check with your browser's network inspector to be sure.) I suspect the field is named differently, or this **would** work.

If it's coming from a file input within a managed form class you should instead be using `$form->get("document")->getData();` to retrieve your `UploadedFile` instance. Guessing from the `form[document]` name you mentioned in a comment, and the output of `$request->files->all()`, this is highly likely the case.

If you really do need to read it raw from the request attributes you'd need to use `$request->files->get("form[document]");` as Symfony would not have expanded the array-like form input name when reading it raw from request attributes. This is the same if you had a text box input, you'd have to read it with `$request->request->get("form[firstName]");`, but as I mentioned you should make proper use of the managed form class way `$form->get("document")->getData();` if this really is a managed form. (Symfony has already thought of this for you in advance, including cascading the input answer to validation rules and data models.)

Otherwise I'd be interested to know how you're uploading this form in the first place. (Is it AJAX?)